# How do I write a SQL Server function to return a single value from result of several queries

Tags: sql-server

I have three tables that contain data relating to a Job. One table is a master table and the other two are transactional and are related to the master.

```
CREATE TABLE Job
(JobNo varchar(10))

CREATE TABLE Trans1
(JobNo varchar(10), TrxDate datetime, TrxStatus int)

CREATE TABLE Trans2
(JobNo varchar(10), TrxDate datetime, TrxStatus int)
```

The `Job` table will always have one row per job. `Trans1` and `Trans2` will have none, one or many rows per job.

I need to be able to write a query that will return, for a given job, what the `TrxStatus` column's value was on a given date.

Let's say `Trans1` has

```
Job     TrxDate    TrxStatus
AB123   2/1/2012     10
AB123   3/1/2012     20
AB123   3/31/2021    20
```

Let's say `Trans2` has

```
Job    TrxDate   TrxStatus
AB123  3/15/2012   10
```

I need to be able to create a function (or have a solution) where I can query:

```
SELECT JobNo, GetStatusAt(JobNo, '3/1/2012') FROM Job
```

and have it return 20.

```
SELECT JobNo, GetStatusAt(JobNo, '3/17/2012') FROM Job
```

and have it return 10.

```
SELECT JobNo, GetStatusAt(JobNo, '4/1/2012') FROM Job
```

and have it return 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  TOP 1
        trxStatus
FROM    (
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1
                *
        FROM    trans1
        WHERE   jobNo = @job
                AND trxDate <= @trxDate
        ORDER BY
                trxDate DESC
        )
        UNION ALL
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1
                *
        FROM    trans2
        WHERE   jobNo = @job
                AND trxDate <= @trxDate
        ORDER BY
                trxDate DESC
        )
        ) q
ORDER BY
        trxDate DESC
```